# How I am able to move Hero container behind all widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, hero

I am trying to apply hero animation on a container that is in a stack "background"
but it keeps pop above all widgets when that happens, I need help please

**Normal design**
[image: normal design]

**when using hero**
[image: when using hero]

this is the widget that uses hero

```html
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomRectangle extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  const CustomRectangle({Key? key, required this.height}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      // flightShuttleBuilder: (flightContext, animation, flightDirection,
      //     fromHeroContext, toHeroContext) {
      //   final toHero = toHeroContext.widget;
      //   if (flightDirection == HeroFlightDirection.pop) {
      //     return FadeTransition(
      //       opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(100),
      //       child: toHero,
      //     );
      //   } else {
      //     return toHero;
      //   }
      // },
      tag: 'animated-rect',
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              AppColors.gradient1,
              AppColors.gradient2,
              AppColors.gradient3
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

First screen that uses hero widget

```html
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/routes/routes.gr.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/utils/app_strings.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/bg_rectangle.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/rounded_container.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/slider_widget.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/task_item.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/text_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var isHome = true;
  bool _visible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CustomRectangle(
          height: 30.h,
        ),
        AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: SizedBox.expand(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 4.h,
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: TextWidget(
                        title: AppStrings.welcomeMessage2,
                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                        textWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1.h,
                    ),
                    const Center(
                        child: TextWidget(title: AppStrings.dashMessage)),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1.h,
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: RoundedContainer(
                        shadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                          ),
                        ],
                        width: 95.w,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.w),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            CircularPercentIndicator(
                              percent: 0.70,
                              radius: 20.w,
                              progressColor: AppColors.progressActiveColor,
                              backgroundColor: AppColors.progressInactiveColor,
                              animation: true,
                              lineWidth: 2.5.w,
                              circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                              center: CircleAvatar(
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                radius: 16.5.w,
                                backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
                                    'assets/images/avatar.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 2.h),
                            const TextWidget(
                              title: AppStrings.progressText,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              textWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 1.h),
                            TextWidget(
                              title: AppStrings.progress,
                              textColor: AppColors.progressActiveColor,
                              fontSize: 20.sp,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 1.h),
                            const TextWidget(
                              title: AppStrings.phaseNum,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              textWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 4.h,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.5.w),
                      child: const Hero(
                        tag: 'tasks-title',
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: TextWidget(
                            textWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            title: "${AppStrings.tasksText}  ",
                            textColor: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1.h,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return const TaskWidget(
                            taskTitle: "Bilder von Fortschritt hochladen",
                            hasIndicator: true,
                            isDay: false,
                          );
                        },
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 6.h,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: SliderWidget(
                height: 20.h,
                onDrag: (dragEndDetails) async {
                  final dx = dragEndDetails.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx;
                  final dy = dragEndDetails.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy;
                  log("dx: $dx, dy: $dy");
                  if ((dy < -100 && dx > 100) || (dy < -100 && dx < -800)) {
                    setState(() {
                      _visible = !_visible;
                    });
                    final result =
                        await context.router.push(const CalendarRoute());
                    if (result == 'calendar') {
                      setState(() {
                        _visible = !_visible;
                      });
                    }
                  } else {
                    log("false");
                  }
                })),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Second screen that uses Hero widget.

```html
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/utils/app_strings.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/bg_rectangle.dart';
import 'package:elithair_mobile_app/widgets/text_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

class CalendarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CalendarPage> createState() => _CalendarPageState();
}

class _CalendarPageState extends State<CalendarPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CustomRectangle(
          height: 7.h,
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.h,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.5.w),
                child: const Hero(
                  tag: 'tasks-title',
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: TextWidget(
                      textWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      title: "${AppStrings.tasksText}  ",
                      textColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
        Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 10.h,
            child: GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTap: () {
                context.router.pop('calendar');
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 2.h,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/svg/ic_arrow_downward.svg',
                ),
              ),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see from the above pictures the widget uses hero when I try to navigate to another screen it pops above the other widgets.
I tried many things but it doesn't work at all, I need help please and thanks!

Comment: please provide some code snippets.

Comment: code is added @reza

Comment: ok. can't find stack

Comment: @reza Please check again

Comment: Seems like there are many dependencies, can you simplify the code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The main problem here that even if the widget in background that uses Hero, when I move to other screen it makes the widget go above every other widget

Comment: What I can guess without testing, you need to move the hero on parent level.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh for the stack? it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem I wrapped the whole Parent widget with The hero , and it seems to work fine